# Python: CARD GAME BOT - Remastering (How do you make a line continue regardless of where it is?)

Tags: python, range, global, definition

I'm remastering the bot by my self and I'm stuck! This is a code which prompts the user to select how many cards they get from the options of

> `7, 9, 11, and 15`

```
def Cards():
    print("Card Amounts")
    print("\nChoices")
    print(7)
    print(9)
    print(11)
    print(15)
    PlayerInput3()
def PlayerInput3():
    global PlayersCards
    PlayerInput = int(raw_input())
    if(PlayerInput == 7):
        PlayersCards == range(1,7)
        print("Lets get started")
        Game()
```

But when they choose how many cards they want it does stay into affect after the definition is over. I want the Players card range to continue in a different defined area. Here:

```
def Game():
    global roundNumber, MyDeck, PlayersCards
    import random
    Select = PlayersCards
    roundNumber = roundNumber + 1
    print("Round %d!") % (roundNumber)
    if(roundNumber == 1) or (roundNumber < 15):
        PlayersCards = random.randint(1, 50)
        MyDeck.append(PlayersCards)
        print("Here are your cards")
        print(MyDeck)
        print("Select a card")
```

But It wont continue on past the

> `def Cards():`

How Can I make it so that the PlayersCard == range(1,7) Continues on regardless of what definition it is in?

Comment: What does the code do now and what do you want it to do

Comment: If you want 9 random numbers, then `My_card_list = [random.randint(1, 100) for x in range(9)]`. Otherwise, are you asking how to index a list?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/7f4ba8f49fcb1702df236a6310b30e19 Here is my code. I'm trying to make it so when the player choses one of the 9 random numbers he got, he doesn't just type in the highest number he can think of

Comment: The game rules are: You get 9 cards each round you select a card from your list and whos ever card is the highest wins

Comment: Also sorry for misleadding you guys if i did. I'm very new to this cite so I didn't know what i was doing

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include additional information. And don't use screenshots for code, thanks

Comment: thx for giving me suggestions

Comment: okay that sounded silly when you said it xD lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code works as you require:

```
def instructions():
    print("You will be playing with an ai and whoever lays down the highest number wins that round.")
    print("The points you get are determined by how much higher your card was from your opponents card.")
    print("The person with the most points wins!")

def getUserInput():
    global roundNumber, My_Deck, PlayerPoints, AIPoints
    My_Deck = []
    roundNumber = 0
    AIPoints = 0
    PlayerPoints = 0
    print ("\nDo you want to play?: ")
    print("\nChoices")
    print("1. Yes")
    print("2. No\n")

    Choice = input()

    if(Choice == 'Yes') or (Choice == 'yes'):
        print("\nOkay, lets get started!")
        startGame()
    elif(Choice in ['No', 'no']):
        print("Okay, bye!")
        quit()
    else:
        print("That is not a Choice!")
        print("Choose 'Yes' or 'No'")
        getUserInput()

def startGame():
    global roundNumber, My_Deck, PlayerPoints, AIPoints
    print("\nAIPoints = %d PlayerPoints = %d" % (AIPoints, PlayerPoints))
    roundNumber = roundNumber + 1
    print("\nRound %d!" % (roundNumber))
    cardChoosen = None
    import random 

    if(roundNumber == 1): 
        print("\nHere are your 9 cards.\n")

        for Cards in range(9):
            Cards = random.randint(1, 100)
            My_Deck.append(Cards)

        while True:
            print("Select one of your cards: "),
            print(My_Deck)
            Select = int(input())
            try:
                if (Select in My_Deck):
                    My_Deck.remove(Select)
                    print("You choose", Select)
                    print("Your deck now is:")
                    print(My_Deck)
                    cardChoosen = Select
                    break
                else:
                    print("You don't have that card in your deck!")
            except ValueError as e:
                print(e)
    elif(roundNumber == 10):
        if(PlayerPoints > AIPoints):
            print("\nCongratulations you won with a score of %d compared to the AI's %d" % (PlayerPoints, AIPoints))
            getUserInput()
        elif(PlayerPoints < AIPoints):
            print("\nUnfortunately you lost with a score of %d compared to the AI's %d" % (PlayerPoints, AIPoints))
            getUserInput()
        else:
            print("\nWow this is basicaly impossible you tied with the AI with you both ahving a score of %d and %d... " % (PlayerPoints, AIPoints))
            getUserInput()
    else:
        print("\nHere are your %d cards.\n" % (9 - roundNumber + 1))

        while True:
            print("Select one of your cards: "),
            print(My_Deck)
            Select = int(input())
            try:
                if (Select in My_Deck):
                    My_Deck.remove(Select)
                    print("You choose", Select)
                    print("Your deck now is:")
                    print(My_Deck)
                    cardChoosen = Select
                    break
                else:
                    print("You don't have that card in your deck!")
            except ValueError as e:
                print(e)    

    AINumber = random.randint(1, 100)

    if(cardChoosen > AINumber):
        print("\nYou won! Your number %d was higher than the AI's number %d" % (cardChoosen, AINumber))
        print("\nYou scored %d points" % (cardChoosen - AINumber))
        PlayerPoints = PlayerPoints + (cardChoosen - AINumber)
        startGame()
    elif(cardChoosen < AINumber):
        print("\nYou Lost! Your number %d was lower than the AI's number %d" % (cardChoosen, AINumber))
        print("\nAI scored %d points" % (AINumber - cardChoosen))
        AIPoints = AIPoints + (AINumber - cardChoosen)
        startGame()
    else:
        print("\nYou tied with the AI! Your number %d was the same as the AI's number %d" % (cardChoosen, AINumber))
        print("\nNobody scored points!")
        startGame()

My_Deck = []
roundNumber = 0
AIPoints = 0
PlayerPoints = 0
instructions()
getUserInput()
```

Comment: I need help i fixed the code you gave me and it works so far but, I the points wont add up :(

Comment: The points add up now but I wont add the code for your last requirement to use the same deck till you accept my answer.

Comment: You cant click the green tick? Wow I had no idea

Comment: Ok I will make it so it uses the same deck give me 15 mins

Comment: also i fixed the score thing now i need it to loop keeping the same score

Comment: Nvm i can click the tick. I thought you meant the arrow xD

Comment: There you go man you can figure it out now, whoever your teacher is, I think hopefully will give you an A+ :), I gtg now I have to do my own assignments.